When I delete data on Swagger I'm getting DataIntegrityViolationException
When I want to Delete data I get this error on Swagger:

{
  "time": "03-10-2024 14:37:40",
  "status": 500,
  "message": "An error occurred",
  "stackTrace": "org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not delete: [com.cloud.atlas.domain.Permission#32]; SQL [UPDATE permission SET is_deleted = true WHERE id=?]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not delete: [com.cloud.atlas.domain.Permission#32]\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.convertHibernateAccessException(HibernateJpaDialect.java:280)\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaDialect.translateExceptionIfPossible(HibernateJpaDialect.java:233)\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:566)\r\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.processCommit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:743)\r\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.support.AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.commit(AbstractPlatformTransactionManager.java:711)\r\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.commitTransactionAfterReturning(TransactionAspectSupport.java:654)\r\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionAspectSupport.invokeWithinTransaction(TransactionAspectSupport.java:407)\r\n\tat org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor.invoke(TransactionInterceptor.java:119)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:698)\r\n\tat com.cloud.atlas.service.impl.PermissionServiceImpl$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$17174a5e.delete(<generated>)\r\n\tat com.cloud.atlas.base.controller.AbstractEntityController.delete(AbstractEntityController.java:23)\r\n\tat com.cloud.atlas.base.controller.AbstractEntityController$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$5e4a6adf.invoke(<generated>)\r\n\tat org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invoke(MethodProxy.java:218)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(CglibAopProxy.java:783)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.invoke(AspectJAfterThrowingAdvice.java:64)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:175)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.aspectj.MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.proceed(MethodInvocationProceedingJoinPoint.java:89)\r\n\tat com.cloud.atlas.config.log.LoggingAspect.logAroundInternal(LoggingAspect.java:56)\r\n\tat com.cloud.atlas.config.log.LoggingAspect.logAroundForLogConsole(LoggingAspect.java:34)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethodWithGivenArgs(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:634)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AbstractAspectJAdvice.invokeAdviceMethod(AbstractAspectJAdvice.java:624)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.aspectj.AspectJAroundAdvice.invoke(AspectJAroundAdvice.java:72)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:175)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.interceptor.ExposeInvocationInterceptor.invoke(ExposeInvocationInterceptor.java:97)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$CglibMethodInvocation.proceed(CglibAopProxy.java:753)\r\n\tat org.springframework.aop.framework.CglibAopProxy$DynamicAdvisedInterceptor.intercept(CglibAopProxy.java:698)\r\n\tat com.cloud.atlas.controller.PermissionController$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$8437b11f.delete(<generated>)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)\r\n\tat java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.doInvoke(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:205)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.method.support.InvocableHandlerMethod.invokeForRequest(InvocableHandlerMethod.java:150)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.invokeAndHandle(ServletInvocableHandlerMethod.java:117)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.invokeHandlerMethod(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:895)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.handleInternal(RequestMappingHandlerAdapter.java:808)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.handle(AbstractHandlerMethodAdapter.java:87)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1067)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:963)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doDelete(FrameworkServlet.java:931)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:687)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883)\r\n\tat javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:327)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.invoke(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:115)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.access.intercept.FilterSecurityInterceptor.doFilter(FilterSecurityInterceptor.java:81)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:122)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.access.ExceptionTranslationFilter.doFilter(ExceptionTranslationFilter.java:116)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:126)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.session.SessionManagementFilter.doFilter(SessionManagementFilter.java:81)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.authentication.AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.doFilter(AnonymousAuthenticationFilter.java:109)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.servletapi.SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter.java:149)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.savedrequest.RequestCacheAwareFilter.doFilter(RequestCacheAwareFilter.java:63)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\r\n\tat com.cloud.atlas.security.CustomAuthenticationFilter.doFilterInternal(CustomAuthenticationFilter.java:61)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:103)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.authentication.logout.LogoutFilter.doFilter(LogoutFilter.java:89)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CorsFilter.doFilterInternal(CorsFilter.java:91)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doHeadersAfter(HeaderWriterFilter.java:90)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.header.HeaderWriterFilter.doFilterInternal(HeaderWriterFilter.java:75)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:110)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.context.SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.doFilter(SecurityContextPersistenceFilter.java:80)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.context.request.async.WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.doFilterInternal(WebAsyncManagerIntegrationFilter.java:55)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy$VirtualFilterChain.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:336)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilterInternal(FilterChainProxy.java:211)\r\n\tat org.springframework.security.web.FilterChainProxy.doFilter(FilterChainProxy.java:183)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.invokeDelegate(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:354)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.DelegatingFilterProxy.doFilter(DelegatingFilterProxy.java:267)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.springframework.boot.actuate.metrics.web.servlet.WebMvcMetricsFilter.doFilterInternal(WebMvcMetricsFilter.java:96)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.CharacterEncodingFilter.doFilterInternal(CharacterEncodingFilter.java:201)\r\n\tat org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:541)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)\r\n\tat org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)\r\n\tat org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:889)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1743)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)\r\n\tat org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)\r\n\tat java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)\r\nCaused by: org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not delete: [com.cloud.atlas.domain.Permission#32]\r\n\tat org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLStateConversionDelegate.convert(SQLStateConversionDelegate.java:115)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:37)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:113)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3727)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3958)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityDeleteAction.execute(EntityDeleteAction.java:123)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:604)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.lambda$executeActions$1(ActionQueue.java:478)\r\n\tat java.base/java.util.LinkedHashMap.forEach(LinkedHashMap.java:684)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:475)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:344)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:40)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.event.service.internal.EventListenerGroupImpl.fireEventOnEachListener(EventListenerGroupImpl.java:107)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.doFlush(SessionImpl.java:1407)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:489)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flushBeforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:3290)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(SessionImpl.java:2425)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.JdbcCoordinatorImpl.beforeTransactionCompletion(JdbcCoordinatorImpl.java:449)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.beforeCompletionCallback(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:183)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.access$300(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:40)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.resource.transaction.backend.jdbc.internal.JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl$TransactionDriverControlImpl.commit(JdbcResourceLocalTransactionCoordinatorImpl.java:281)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.TransactionImpl.commit(TransactionImpl.java:101)\r\n\tat org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager.doCommit(JpaTransactionManager.java:562)\r\n\t... 122 more\r\nCaused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: The column index is out of range: 2, number of columns: 1.\r\n\tat org.postgresql.core.v3.SimpleParameterList.bind(SimpleParameterList.java:69)\r\n\tat org.postgresql.core.v3.SimpleParameterList.setBinaryParameter(SimpleParameterList.java:136)\r\n\tat org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.bindBytes(PgPreparedStatement.java:1047)\r\n\tat org.postgresql.jdbc.PgPreparedStatement.setLong(PgPreparedStatement.java:307)\r\n\tat com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.HikariProxyPreparedStatement.setLong(HikariProxyPreparedStatement.java)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BigIntTypeDescriptor$1.doBind(BigIntTypeDescriptor.java:46)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder.bind(BasicBinder.java:73)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:276)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.type.AbstractStandardBasicType.nullSafeSet(AbstractStandardBasicType.java:271)\r\n\tat org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.delete(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3681)\r\n\t... 141 more\r\n"
}

All endpoints worked only delete endpoints not working. I'm working on Base Entity for my code readability:
package com.cloud.atlas.base.entity;

import lombok.Data;
import lombok.EqualsAndHashCode;
import lombok.NoArgsConstructor;
import lombok.ToString;
import lombok.experimental.SuperBuilder;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedBy;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.CreatedDate;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.LastModifiedBy;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.LastModifiedDate;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.domain.support.AuditingEntityListener;

import javax.persistence.*;

import java.io.Serializable;
import java.time.LocalDateTime;

@SuperBuilder
@EntityListeners({ AuditingEntityListener.class })
@Data
@EqualsAndHashCode
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity implements Serializable {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", length = 50)
    protected Long id;

    @CreatedDate
    @Column(name = "created_at")
    protected LocalDateTime createdAt;

    @LastModifiedDate
    @Column(name = "updated_at")
    protected LocalDateTime updatedAt;

    @Column(name = "deleted_at")
    protected LocalDateTime deletedAt;

    @Column(name = "is_active", nullable = false)
    private boolean isActive = true;

    @Column(name = "is_deleted", nullable = false)
    private boolean isDeleted = false;

    @CreatedBy
    @Column(name = "created_by")
    private String createdBy;

    @LastModifiedBy
    @Column(name = "updated_by")
    private String updatedBy;

    @Version
    @Column(name = "version")
    private Long version;

    @PrePersist
    public void onCreate() {
        this.createdAt = LocalDateTime.now();
        this.updatedAt = LocalDateTime.now();
    }

    @PreUpdate
    public void onUpdate() {
        this.updatedAt = LocalDateTime.now();
    }

    public abstract <T extends BaseEntity> void update(T entity);
}

And Permission model:
@EqualsAndHashCode(callSuper = false)
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
@Entity
@Table(name = "permission")
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE permission SET is_deleted = true WHERE id=?")
@Where(clause = "is_deleted=false")
public class Permission  extends BaseEntity {

    @Column(nullable = false)
    private String alias;
    @Column
    private String author;

    @Column
    private String title;
    @Column
    private String description;

    @Column
    private Integer status;

    @Override
    public <T extends BaseEntity> void update(T entity) {
        Permission permission = (Permission) entity;
        this.alias = permission.alias;
        this.title = permission.title;
        this.description = permission.description;
        this.status = permission.status;
        this.author = permission.author;
    }
}

Terminal Says:
nput: [100]
output: could not delete: [com.cloud.atlas.domain.Permission#100]; SQL [UPDATE permission SET is_deleted = true WHERE id=?]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not delete: [com.cloud.atlas.domain.Permission#100]
2024-10-03 10:33:16.710 ERROR 22188 --- [nio-9060-exec-3] GLOBAL_EXCEPTION_HANDLER                 : An error occurred

org.springframework.dao.DataIntegrityViolationException: could not delete: [com.cloud.atlas.domain.Permission#100]; SQL [UPDATE permission SET is_deleted = true WHERE id=?]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.DataException: could not delete: [com.cloud.atlas.domain.Permission#100]

When I researched this problem, the solution says if you are using a nullable command you need to use a length like this: @Column(nullable = false, length = 4096) and this does not solve my problem.
Wrong but If I can't solve I'm gonna add a Soft Delete endpoint with PUT annotation and just update is_deleted part to true.
Thank you for your help!
Edit: When I delete these lines problem is solved but delete is not soft anymore:
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE permission SET is_deleted = true WHERE id=?")
@Where(clause = "is_deleted=false")


@talexmovedtoCodidact added to full error when delete request work on swagger.

Are you using Spring Data?  If so, you probably just need to modify your "delete" query to include the version as the second parameter:
change
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE permission SET is_deleted = true WHERE id=?")

to
@SQLDelete(sql = "UPDATE permission SET is_deleted = true WHERE id=? and version=?")


Yes, it solves my problem, but why do I need to add a version to soft delete?

It's documented in the most unclear way possible in the hibernate documentation, "The primary key columns come before the version column if the entity is versioned."  So, because your entity is versioned, you have to add parameters for your keys (id) and then add a parameter for the version.  See the documentation here
